# Zend application.ini vs config.ini (or xml) - where should db credentials go?

Tags: php, zend-framework, config

I have seen a lot of code snippets on the web and examples showing different variations of `Zend_Config` and application.ini. Additionally, I have seen some debates about ini config files vs xml config files. I personally have **application.ini** *and* a **config.xml** file.

- My application.ini just has basic stuff like php settings and and front controller settings, etc
- My config.xml file has some site settings and it also has the db adapter info

As the Zend Framework has progressed I've seen more and more people put almost everything (or so it seems) in **application.ini**. Should I do the same?

Comment: Soft reason: INI files are more user-friendly. XML was intended as document format base, less for key value data storage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @mario says .ini style is way more readable for mortals beings while at the same time being not too bad to parse programatically. XML is wizzy easy for parsing (well it is in stuff like java) but awful to read and navigate through. Unless you really need to I would recommend sticking to just using .ini style files. You'll find it alot easier for other people to get up to speed on what configs 'doing'. That said you aren't stuck to just using one config file so feel free to break down configuration sections into multiple .ini files if it makes sense.

Comment: Ok, so it's "_normal_" to have more than just the application.ini config file? I was starting to get the impression that I was the only one lol.

Comment: @mmmshuddup , I currently have one application.ini for global site settings. Then module.ini files for submodules, and occasionally server specific ini files that sit outside the site folder which are inherited by everything (contains things such as DataBase info so i can keep passwords out of code repositories), (I run multiple sites per server)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'm going to try to refactor that in my app now.